# How to refresh full calendar in js after the db changes?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I gone through many resources and documentation ,  still i faced only the errors in removing and adding the new events to fullcalendar .

Also i tried by using refetch events to refresh , still not worked for me .

```
var auto_refresh=setInterval(function()
{  $("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
},10000);
```

Also i tried this , it takes the data correctly but events couldnt add to the calendar

```
 var auto_refresh=setInterval(function()
    {
      var url_event='take_events.php?id='+ id +'$role='+ role;
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents'); 
         $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', url_event); 
    
    },10000);
```

Comment: How did you add the events  to the calendar originally? Are there any console errors when you try to run the code above? What version of fullcalendar are you using? Please provide more info then we can help you easily. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying but i solved it , i used 3 rd version of full calendar.

Comment: I just came to know that its parameter error  $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', url_event,true);

Answer (score 1):

Here i solved by adding true to the addeventsource

```
$("#demo-calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', jsonval,true);
```

Please note that this will work for only 3. versions of fullcalendar.